# HttpClient Portable returns 404 notfound on WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, portable-class-library, dotnet-httpclient

I'm porting a W8 application that uses httpclient library to connect to our server.

The main purpose of the application is to send images, but when I try to send pictures on my WP8 I got a 404 not found error (seems that Microsoft remapped to 404 a lot of errors), if i check the server logs, I can see that the server recevied about 1/4 of the image before failling. The same function seems to works fine in my W8 application (didn't tested on 3G), and works on WP8 if I use Wifi connection. I think that the problem could be the waiting time, so I tried to add Keep-Alive headers without success.
The current code I have is:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

    Stream streamW = new MemoryStream();
    this.bSyncOK = await Send(streamW);
    streamW.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(sUri, new StreamContent(streamW));

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Stream streamR = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        this.bSyncOK = await Recv(streamR);
        streamR.Dispose();
    }
    else
        throw new HostNotFoundException();
}
```

The same server is used to upload pictures on other platforms like IOS and Android without problems.

Comment: Did you try capturing a network trace?

Comment: @TheESJ I tried to use Wireshark and I can see that the server starts to receive the stream but suddenly stops receiving information. After a lot of retries, I'm able to send a picture (maybe 20-30 retries).

Comment: Would it be possible to share the full repro code?

Comment: Sorry, my company doesn't let me to share the code. But I think that you can reproduce the issue sending a stream of about 1.4mb with low connectivity speed (2G).

Comment: I made a little project where you can check the issue, its important to set the network to 2G mode. You only need to change the sUri in the sync class to any url that its able to receive a big post call [link](https://mega.co.nz/#!akBjRYwD!XgpqHFyV95GewGSZxqfIcyLxOJZHZVtFtF6nFMAkhU4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced the problem using fiddler to simulate modem speeds.  The problem is happening because Phone's HTTPWebRequest implementation will timeout the request whenever it exceeds around 60s.  In the debugger I see them getting back ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT from their native layer.  The only workaround I can think of at the moment would be to send the file in smaller POSTs, assuming the server supports that.

Comment: Thanks @TheESJ for your help, I already implemted a picture split to try to avoid this issue. In my multiples tryes I made a C++ component, but with the same result, so seems that there is an issue with the network implementation.