# HttpClient timeouts before the timeout specified

Tags: windows-phone-8, timeout, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using HttpClient from WP8 and do a Post request. I know the call may take long time as I'm actually simulating slow network scenarios. Therefore I set the `HttpClient.Timeout` accordingly to 5 minutes.

However, I get a Timeout at around 60s. I believe the Timeout is not working.
I believe there is an issue with this for WP as stated in this question: 
[HttpClient Portable returns 404 notfound on WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915246/httpclient-portable-returns-404-notfound-on-wp8).

They use a workaround but that does not applies to my scenario. I do actually want to wait for long time.

My questions:

1) Is it a bug/issue of HttpClient for WP8 or I'm not setting it properly?
2) Do you think of a workaround still using HttpClient?

I've read that maybe HttpWebRequest is an option. However, I believe HttpClient should be ideal for this 'simple' scenario.

My code is simple:

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(Uri serverUri, HttpContent httpContent)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    return await client.PostAsync(serverUri, httpContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

The server receives the request and while is processing it, the client aborts.

UPDATE: The `HttpResponseMessage` returned by `HttpClient.PostAsyn` is this `"{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: '', Version: 0.0, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: {   Content-Length: 0 }}"`. As I said, the server is found and is receiving the data and processing it.

Comment: Are you sure that the server is not timing out after 60 seconds?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I'm actually running the server as well and I see the progress. The server performs some cpu intensive process before replying to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search and some tests I've came to the conclusion that the problem is Windows Phone itself and that it has a 60 seconds timeout (irrespective of the HttpClient) and that cannot be changed to my knowledge. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/faf00a04-8a2e-4a64-b1c1-74c52cf685d3/httpwebrequest-60-seconds-timeout.

As I'm programming the server as well, I will try the advice by Darin Rousseau in the link provided above, specifically to send an OK and then do some more processing.

---

UPDATE: The problem seems to be the Windows Phone emulator as stated here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-us/6c114ae9-4dc1-4e1f-afb2-a6b9004bf0c6/httpclient-doesnt-work-on-windows-phone?forum=wpdevelop. In my experience the tcp connection times-out if it doesn't hear anything for 60s.

---

Therefore my solution is to use the Http header characters as a way of keep alive. The first line Http header response always starts with `HTTP/1.0`. So I send the characters one by one with a delay <60s between them. Of course, if the response gets ready, everything that is left is sent right away. This buys some time, for instance if using a delay of 50s per 9 character we get about 450s.

This is a project for my degree so I wouldn't recommend it for production.

By the way, I also tried with other characters instead the sub string of the header, for instance space character, but that results in a http protocol violation.

This is the main part of the code:

```
    private const string Header1 = @"HTTP/1.0 ";
    private int _keepAliveCounter = 0;
    private readonly object _sendingLock = new object();
    private bool _keepAliveDone = true;

    private void StartKeepAlive()
    {
        Task.Run(() => KeepAlive());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Keeps the connection alive sending the first characters of the http response with an interval.
    /// This is a hack for Windows Phone 8 that need reponses within 60s interval.
    /// </summary>
    private void KeepAlive()
    {
        try
        {
            _keepAliveDone = false;
            _keepAliveCounter = 0;
            while (!_keepAliveDone && _keepAliveCounter < Header1.Length)
            {
                Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50)).Wait();
                lock (_sendingLock)
                {
                    if (!_keepAliveDone)
                    {
                        var sw = new StreamWriter(OutputStream);
                        sw.Write(Header1[_keepAliveCounter]);
                        Console.Out.WriteLine("Wrote keep alive char '{0}'", Header1[_keepAliveCounter]);
                        _keepAliveCounter++;
                        sw.Flush();
                    }
                }
            }
            _keepAliveCounter = 0;
             _keepAliveDone = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // log the exception
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Error while sending keepalive: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Then, the actual processing happens in a different thread.

Comments and critics are appreciated.

Comment: The problem is not limited to the Windows Phone 8 emulator. I get the issue on a real device as well (Nokia Lumia 830). I am trying to use HttpClient to send a PUT request that takes longer than 60 seconds and I get the 404 error.

Comment: Good to know. (I guess you set the timeout to something higher than 60 seconds?) It must be in the .Net's portable implementation, or the OS too.. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Yes - I set my timeout to 10 minutes, but the 404 error throws at 60 seconds anyway. I have some lengthy synchronous requests that need to complete. I have found no way to increase timeout beyond 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are hitting the timeout of the network stream.  You can change this by doing,

```
var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
handler.ReadWriteTimeout= 5 * 60 * 1000;
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
return await client.PostAsync(serverUri, httpContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The default on the desktop OS is already 5mins.  However, it is possible that on Windows Phone it has been reduced by default.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I tried but unfortunately `WebRequestHandler` is not available for WP.

Comment: @JB  I thought that initially too, however for some reason, the MSDN docs say that it is.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.webrequesthandler(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There is HttpClientHandler but it does not a Timeout.

Comment: @jb Yeah, the HttpClientHandler is the default handler.